# Can Terraform be run from inside an AWS WorkSpace?

Tags: terraform, amazon-workspaces

I'm trying to figure out a way to run Terraform from inside an AWS WorkSpace.  Is that even possible? Has anyone made this work?

Answer (score 1):

AWS WorkSpaces doesn't apply the same concept with an Instance Profile and associated IAM role that is attached to it.

I'm pretty confident, however, that you can run Terraform in an AWS WorkSpace just as you can do it from your personal computer. With Internet access (or VPC endpoints), it can reach AWS APIs and just requires a set of credentials, which in this case (without instance profiles) would be an AWS Access Key and Secret Access Key - just like on your local computer.